# How to correctly write a unit test for controllers methods in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5.5

Please check the code I used to in my controller:

```
class ObjectsPagesController extends Controller
{
    public function destroy(Destroy $destroy, $id)
    {
        $objectsPage = ObjectsPages::with( 'ObjectsPagesRelation')->where('group_id', $id)->first();
        if (isset($objectsPage)) {

            $objectsPage->delete();
            $objectsPage->ObjectsPagesRelation()->delete();
            return redirect()->route('objects.pages.index')->with('success', 'done');  

        }else{
            abort(404);
        }
    }
}
```

On my request page, I wrote the codes below:

```
class Destroy extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::user()->can('del_objects_pages');
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

I try the artisan command like below

```
php artisan make:test Pages --unit`
```

But a clear instruction could not be found for laravel 5.5 what to do next?

Comment: If you are just starting out I recommend using Laravel 5.6 and watch some free videos on Laracasts how to do stuff. You basically do not unit-test controllers you make integration (feature) tests. *Given this input controller produces some output and assert that.* Thumbs up that you are trying to test your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
  class StoreObjectPageTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testStoreObjectIsCreated()
    {
        $this->actingAs($someUser)->post('/some/url');

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('store_objects', [
            // The attributes of a row you're expecting to see in DB
        ]);
    }
}
?>
```